# Missing return statement in method with if conditions in recyclerview adapter

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I really don't know why i'm getting in this method an error for not returning any value. It's about method `getItemViewType()` in `RecyclerView.Adapter`. I'm checking for some condition inside.

```
@Override
@ViewType
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    if (!mResults.isEmpty()) {
        if (position < mResults.size()) {
            if (itemList.get(position) instanceof Categorizable) {
                return TYPE_ITEM;
            } else if (itemList.get(position) instanceof SectionHeader) {
                return TYPE_SECTION_HEADER;
            }
        } else {
            return FOOTER;
        }
    } else {
        if (mFilterOption == Filter.COMPLETE ||
                mFilterOption == Filter.INCOMPLETE) {
            if (position == 0) {
                return NO_ITEM;
            } else {
                return FOOTER;
            }
        } else {
            if (itemList.get(position) instanceof Categorizable) {
                return TYPE_ITEM;
            } else {
                return TYPE_SECTION_HEADER;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Add a return value before the last }.

Comment: Just add return NO_ITEM to last line of method.

Comment: That's not the problem, check out my answer. I actually pasted the code in my Android studio and managed to get it fixed. @greenapps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I got it, one of your conditions is not covered. Look at the first `if`, and look where I added `return 1;`, you were missing a return statement in case it enters there but it does not fulfill any of the above 2 conditions:

```
if (!mResults.isEmpty()) {
        if (position < mResults.size()) {
            if (itemList.get(position) instanceof Categorizable) {
                return TYPE_ITEM;
            } else if (itemList.get(position) instanceof SectionHeader) {
                return TYPE_SECTION_HEADER;
            }
            return 1; // adding this will fix it
        } else {
            return FOOTER;
        }
    } else {
        if (mFilterOption == Filter.COMPLETE ||
                mFilterOption == Filter.INCOMPLETE) {
            if (position == 0) {
                return NO_ITEM;
            } else {
                return FOOTER;
            }
        } else {
            if (itemList.get(position) instanceof Categorizable) {
                return TYPE_ITEM;
            } else {
                return TYPE_SECTION_HEADER;
            }
        }
    }
```

Of course, replace `1` with the actual value it's supposed to return there. Also, when you have `return`s you don't actually need `else`s most of the time. Take a look at this example:

```
if (a > b) return a;
else return b;
```

And compare it to this (just to get the idea):

```
if (a > b) return a;
return b;
```

So the second one may be a bit more readable, and it does the same thing. If the `if` condition was fulfilled, it would've returned `a`. If not, no need for `else`, it's obsolete. Maybe removing some `else`s in your code may make it more clear and readable.

Comment: Great! Will start using that in future.

Comment: No problem bro. Have fun coding. I daj neki plus i prihvati odgovor drugu :D

Comment: Hocu druze, samo za koji sat. Ne moze odmah, znas vec. :D